# Cannot avoid "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: default for column "gender" cannot be cast automatically to type integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to change gender column to integer in my rails app. It is said that when using postgresql, we have to write a little bit different way. i.e.

```
change_column :users, :gender, :integer, using: 'gender::integer'
```

or

```
change_column :users, :gender, 'integer USING CAST(gender AS integer)'
```

However, in my case, the aboves are still not working and got the below error.

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  default for column "gender" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "gender" TYPE integer USING gender::integer
```

Please tell me why it doesn't work. Or some weird things I've got? For example typo.

My environment

- Ruby: 2.5.0
- Rails: 5.1.6
- Postgres: 11.1

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you're seeing, Postgres does not know how to keep the default value you've set while changing the database type to integer. I'd suggest:

1. Dropping the default
2. Changing the datatype on the column
3. Adding the default in the new type

You may be able to do steps 2 and 3 in the same call. You'll want to use something like the below in the up migration:

```
def up
  execute "ALTER TABLE users ALTER gender DROP DEFAULT;"
  change_column :users, :gender, :integer, using: 'gender::integer', default: 0
end
```

Comment: thanks! In my case, drop down gender column first, after that I inserted ```change_column :users, :gender, :integer, default: 0``` and it works. but how you could read that the error indicated Postgres did not know how to keep the default value?

Comment: In the error message you posted, `ERROR:  default for column "gender" cannot be cast automatically to type integer` the 'default for column "gender"' referred to the column's existing default value.

Comment: I didn’t know the value means in the context of databases... but now I understood. Thanks.